# Not receiving Chat notifications in main menu bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I remember back a few months ago when I was really into the SciFi&Fantassy SE site, there would be constant notifications when someone would ping you or mention your name.

When I left the site for a brief period and came back and I no longer receive these notifications. Is this an issue for all sites?

Answer (score 1):

Stated this when the top bar was implemented..... apparently that 20 minute delay until they hit the inbox is the new method. No more immediate notifications if you're on the site.

Note, you **do** get instant pings (notifications) if you have the chat window open. It's only when the chat window is not open in a browser that the notifications are delayed.

Comment: I remember a week or so ago when you pinged me in chat. I never received that notification even after a day or so when I remembered to check to see if someone answered my question.

Comment: Yeah it's really slow and undependable now.

Answer (score 1):

This [*was* a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210072/216955), but it was fixed. As Scott points out, there's just [a delay](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153323/216955) to recieve pings.

Since you got [this ping](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13098500#13098500), I've marked this as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)